# Why such a line in the movie Arjun Patiala?

Tags: arjun-patiala

Why is the movie *[Arjun Patiala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arjun_Patiala)* called the 245th movie about police or cops?

They say it is the 245th film on cops in the trailer.

What is the basis of this count? Is it real or was just some random number assigned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just a comedy spoof on Bollywood cop films. There is no particular basis of this count. They just assigned a random number.

From [Urban Asian's interview](https://urbanasian.com/entertainment/bollywood/2019/07/ua-exclusive-diljit-dosanjh-i-dont-know-if-it-is-the-245th-cop-film/) with Diljit Dosanjh, the lead actor,

> Diljit was asked about the film and about if it is the 245th cop film he said
>
> > “**I don’t know if it is the 245th cop film, I have not counted.** So when I asked what is the theme of the film they (makers) told me there is no theme, it’s a fun comedy film. I like the people on the film so I did it.”